# Passing Variables from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a batch file

Tags: stored-procedures, batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL Server that takes some data and must to send it to a batch file, wich will send those data like variables to a jar file. BAT and JAR is all ok. But my problem is to make it possible from the Stored Procedure...  Here is the code that I'm ussing, but for some reasson, it tell me that 'The system cannot find the path specified.'

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_testeCarimbadorPDF](
        @Path VARCHAR(1000),
        @numCarimb int 
     )
   AS

   BEGIN
   DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
   DECLARE @NUMERO VARCHAR(10)
   SELECT @NUMERO = CONVERT(varchar(10),@numCarimb)

   SET @CMDSQL = 'C:\TESTE\CarimbadorPDF.bat' + ' ' + @Path + ' ' + @NUMERO
   exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMDSQL
   waitfor delay '00:00:02'
   end
```

Which one is my mistake? I need to send those variables to the batch file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path that you given is SQL Server related path not your local path. The `exec master..xp_cmdshell @CMDSQL` executes the command on the sql server machine not in your local machine. It can work only if you SQL server runs on your local machine.

Comment: The @Path variable, is just a path recognized by the *.bat file. But I thought that master..xp_cmdshell run actually local files...

Comment: @user1729626 Is your SQL server instance on your local machine?